# Show 5 days along x axis with panning

Tags: flot

I'm trying to show only 5 points along the x axis, with panning enabled - I want the user to pan through the other points beyond 5.

I have disabled the zoom, but my problem seems to be that the more data I add, the points along the x axis starts to try and increase.

So if I load 20 points worth of data, instead of showing the 5 points which the user then should simply pan to the other 15, the x axis "zooms out" to show as many points as possible.

also, How do I set the start position? In that if there are 20 points, and only points are showing, how do I set the view to start at point 10 to 15, so the user pans back to the first 10 points, and pans forward for the remaining 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these options for your x axis:

```
xaxis: {
  panRange: [0, 20],
  min: 5,
  max: 10
}
```

`panRange` defines the borders of the range to pan and `min & max` define the start range.

**Edit:** You can specify an array with ticknames:

```
  var ticks = [
    [1, 'one'],
    [2, 'two'],
```

and use it like this:

```
    xaxis: {
      ...
      ticks: ticks,
```

See the code snippet below for a full example:

```js
$(function() {

  var data = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 2],
    [6, 3],
    [7, 3],
    [8, 2],
    [9, 1],
    [10, 1],
    [11, 3],
    [12, 4],
    [13, 2],
    [14, 2],
    [15, 4],
    [16, 3],
    [17, 3],
    [18, 1],
    [19, 4]
  ];
  
  var ticks = [
    [1, 'one'],
    [2, 'two'],
    [3, 'three'],
    [4, 'four'],
    [5, 'five'],
    [6, 'six'],
    [7, 'seven'],
    [8, 'eight'],
    [9, 'nine'],
    [10, 'ten'],
    [11, 'eleven'],
    [12, 'twelve'],
    [13, 'thirteen'],
    [14, 'fourteen'],
    [15, 'fifteen'],
    [16, 'sixteen'],
    [17, 'seventeen'],
    [18, 'eighteen'],
    [19, 'nineteen']
  ];

  var options = {
    series: {
      points: {
        show: true
      },
      lines: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      panRange: [0, 20],
      min: 5,
      max: 10,
      ticks: ticks,
      tickDecimals: 0
    },
    yaxis: {
      panRange: [0, 5],
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      tickDecimals: 0
    },
    zoom: {
      interactive: false
    },
    pan: {
      interactive: true
    }
  };

  var plot = $.plot('#placeholder', [data], options);

});
```

```css
#placeholder {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Just a last question, as I can see you know what you're doing, how do I add custom string labels to the X Axis?